# How to build a classification model for three classes and partially missing labels?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, supervised-learning

### I got this interview question. Would like to know the correct answer:

In our population, there are 10,000 customers. We sample 1,000 of these people to offer a product. We know

```
 1. Some don’t accept offer anymore. 
 2. Some accept if we call them
 3. Some accept anyway.
```

How we can exclude the customers in the first item in the remaining population (10,000 - 1,000 = 9,000)? We have historical data of all people but only 1,000 are proposed this offer and may/may not return back the result.

### My solution:

I think we need two classifiers
First classifier: looks if customer accepts or not. If it is Yes, so the customer belongs to item-3. Otherwise, the customer is processed by the second classifier
Second classifier: looks if customer accepts if receives call. If yes, so he is in item 2; otherwise in item 1.
My big concern is the problem says there is no guarantee all 1000 customers return the result back (it means their decisions are unknown). Do I need to consider them as NO?

Comment: the question is not clear. Do you know who the 1000 customers are which belong to class 1 (don't accept offer anymore) ? If yes, what is the problem ? If no, how do you know these are exactly 1000 ? Some confusion is generated by "anymore", since this implies rather a customer flag then a target to predict (compared to "reject offer" for instance). Furthermore: As far as I understand, the historical data contains reactions to different offers, but for only 1000 customers to the current offer. Is this correct ?

Comment: you know about 1000 customers but not about 9000 rest. All 1000 receive the same offer

Comment: aside: Anyone interested in this area might take a look at [Uplift modelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uplift_modelling)

Answer (score 3):

Your population has size 10k and you have a sample of 1k for which you know their state:

1. Some don’t accept offer anymore.
2. Some accept if we call them
3. Some accept anyway.

You encode this state as a nominal variable with 3 levels.

Fit a classifier using all the things you know about clients as input variables and state variable as target variable.

Using this model, predict the state for the other 10k - 1k = 9k data points from the population.

Remove all the data points classified as 1. Don't accept offer anymore

Comment: My concern is a fraction of these 1000 customers (who received the offer) will respond.

Comment: That means you have censored data. I know little on this topic, but there is a large literature on methods for dealing with censored data.

Comment: @BigDataLover [Semi-supervised learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-supervised_learning) might be worth a look to include the customers which did not respond into the model. I second this answer (+1). I think it is better then your solution because building two binary models instead of one trinary model will lead to an increased error since you have to perform a classification decision in between.